# Mostrar calendário gerado com JS mostrando informações do DB

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou gerando um calendário e inserindo os eventos com informações pegas no banco de dados.
Quando o select traz apenas um resultado ele e exibido normalmente, mas quando há mais de um o calendário não e exibido.
O erro estaria no laço de repetição ou não e possível trazer os resultados?

**Select usado**

```
$sql_principal = "SELECT obras.titulo_traduzido, obras.data_lancamento, obras.id FROM obras where obras.id=1161";
$resultado_principal = mysql_query($sql_principal);
```

**Script que gera o Calendario**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2015-10-23',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [<?php
            while($objeto = mysql_fetch_object($resultado_principal)){
                  echo "{";
                     echo "title: '{$objeto->titulo_traduzido}',";
                     echo "start: '{$objeto->data_lancamento}',";
                     echo "url: 'http://localhost/admin/filme.php?ID={$objeto->id}'";
                 echo "},";
            }
            ?>]
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro??

Comment: Não e retornado nenhum erro, a tela simplesmente fica em branco, não retornando nada nem mesmo o calendário já gerado.

Comment: Um exemplo, se eu usar "SELECT obras.titulo_traduzido, obras.data_lancamento, obras.id FROM obras where obras.id=1161", ele traz o calendário com o evento marcado no dia correto, agora se select for sem a clausura WHERE para trazer todos os eventos a tela fica em branco.

Comment: Peguei seu script, coloquei aqui e funcionou. Você tem o firebug do firefox ou então no Chrome, aperta F12 e clica em Console. Veja se tem algum erro de JS

Comment: Usando o Console percebi que o select está trazendo muitos registros, fazendo com que demore para ser processado ou até mesmo trave o calendário. Coloquei um Between no campo data_lancamento e deu certo.

Comment: Você saberia me dizer se tem como colocar no select o BETWEEN para pegar o mês que esta sendo exibido pelo calendário?
Tipo, eu seleciono no calendário o mês de Dezembro e no select ficaria: SELECT obras.titulo_traduzido, obras.data_lancamento, obras.id FROM obras data_lancamento BETWEEN '2015-12-01' and '2015-12-31'
sendo que quando eu mudar o mês no calendário mude no select também

Comment: Você pode fazer o seguinte.... Guarde todos os registros que vieram do banco em um array JS sendo a chave desse array o "mes/ano" do evento, algo do tipo arrayEventos['2015-11'][] = 'teste1' e assim por diante. Quando o usuário trocar o mês no calendário, o FullCalendar tem uma função getMonth() para você pegar o mês 'ativo'. Limpe o calendário usando a função removeElements e depois adicione esse array do mês correspondente ao calendário. Parece difícil mas não é.